# Volume between $z=13-x^2-y^2$ and $z=4 \sqrt{x^2+y^2} + 1$ Polar Integration

Tags: calculus, integration

Find volume between $z=13-x^2-y^2$ and $z=4 \sqrt{x^2+y^2} + 1$

My attempt:
Convert to polar, and find intersections.

$r^2=x^2+y^2$, giving $z=13-r^2$ and $z=4r+1$

This means $r=-6, 2$

I just assume $\theta$ is from $0$ to $2\pi$, not sure if this is correct.

I setup this integral but the answer is not $56/3  \pi$...

$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{-6}^2 (13-r^2)-(4r+1) rdrd\theta$

What is wrong with my attempt?

Comment: $r$ cannot be less than 0. If you change your limits of integration on $r$ from $(-6,2)$ to $(0,2)$, you should get the right answer

Comment: Oh thanks, that makes sense!